# How can I get access to property from another view controller in iOS?

Tags: ios, properties

I'm developing an application that contains a menuViewController  ( tableViewController) which has a cell called "profileCell" that display user's first name which can be imported from another viewController "userViewController" that has user's first name property recovered from login Facebook or twitter or google plus.My problem is that the property firstName isn't null in the "userViewController" but when I want to access it in the menuViewController , it return a null.I have searched in the net and I have seen other similar issues but I can't resolve my issue.

This my code :

```
    case 2 : {


        NSString *cellIdentifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"profileCell"];
        profileTableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        UserViewController *userVC = [[UserViewController alloc]init];
        cell.cellNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userVC.firstName];

        return cell;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create new UserViewController there, I suppose.

Does your menuViewController have property or variable pointing to UserViewController? If so, then you should use this stored value.

Answer (score 0):

An user's name would remain the same once he is logged in to the app. So why don't you save the name using NSUserDefaults and access it from rest of the app?

That way the two controllers wouldn't have to interact with each other.

Comment: do i Choose NSUserDefaults or NSkeyedArchiver?

Comment: NUUserDefaults makes more sense in your use case I think